# What Javascript framework should I use with the following requirements?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I was wondering if anyone can help in choosing a framework as this is my requirement:

1. We have to use our own model, we have an internal JS Database that is our model that sits inside the browser and syncs with the remote server, so this is a deal breaker as we have to use our Model and not the framework's... We will have to manually handle any mapping between GET and SET any data from and to, the Model... (can I even use a JS Framework with this requirement)
2. We will use Bootstrap for the UI so we don't need any Framework that comes with UI such as Ext JS, we need pure framework
3. We would like (but don't have to) keep using jQuery. This is not a deal breaker, but if we can continue and use jQuery it will make our learning curve shorter.
4. We need good Routing capabilities including the ability to change the actual View (i.e.: show hide DIV of current selected route) and not just fire an event when new Route is selected.
5. Binding and Templates would be a plus (I believe all good frameworks have it)
6. A light Framework would be better, but not a must.

Comment: Framework suggestion requests are off topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: Sounds like Knockout and Angular.js would do the trick ;)

Comment: Where else should @user2040670 ask?

Comment: the problem is that Knockout doesnt support Routes and Angular has its own model

Comment: Ok, how about just using jquery with jquery-tmpl? That should work. If I can ask, why has it to be js?